# Getting a specific node in XML using XPATH

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Here is my XML output, I need to get the value **87654321** using a simple xpath expression which is of Custom_ID = TN, note that the position of this TN Custom_ID might not be always in the second or last position so I can't use last().

```
<Root>
    <Data>
        <Personal>
            <IDs>
                <Custom_ID>
                    <Custom_ID_Data>
                        <ID>12345678</ID>
                        <ID_Type_Reference>
                            <ID type="Custom_ID">ID</ID>
                        </ID_Type_Reference>
                    </Custom_ID_Data>
                </Custom_ID>
                <Custom_ID>
                    <Custom_ID_Data>
                        <ID>87654321</ID>
                        <ID_Type_Reference>
                            <ID type="Custom_ID">TN</ID>
                        </ID_Type_Reference>
                    </Custom_ID_Data>
                </Custom_ID>
            </IDs>
        </Personal>
    </Data>
</Root>
```

========================================================================

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `//Custom_ID/Custom_ID_Data[ID_Type_Reference/ID[@type = 'Custom_ID'] = 'TN']/ID` you select the `ID` element(s), if you really want a string value then use `string(//Custom_ID/Custom_ID_Data[ID_Type_Reference/ID[@type = 'Custom_ID'] = 'TN']/ID)` in XSLT 1.0 to get the string of the first selected node in XSLT/XPath 1.0 or `//Custom_ID/Custom_ID_Data[ID_Type_Reference/ID[@type = 'Custom_ID'] = 'TN']/ID/string()` to get a sequence of strings of any selected nodes in XSLT/XPath 2.0.